# HandleError and strongly typed layout in ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.MVC 4. I have a strongly typed layout which is connected to a base view model (every other view model is inheriting from the base view model). I'm trying to handle errors using a standard HandleError filter. It's out of box configured and works if layout isn't strongly typed.

My example exception is following:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("oops");
    }
}
```

When the mechanism tries to plug Error page into strongly typed layout it gets in trouble because there's no model for it.

Does anyone know what is a scenario for using strongly typed layouts with the HandleError filter? Is there any possibility to set model for the layout before the exception is thrown?

EDIT:

Possible solution is turning off standard error handling mechanism and catching exceptions in the Application_Error method in the Global.asax. Example solution you can find here: [ASP.MVC HandleError attribute doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357340/asp-mvc-handleerror-attribute-doesnt-work)

Anyway - if someone have another solution, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I can think of is

- a) In Global.asax.cs, handle Application_Error (or
  Application_OnError, the signature escapes me now) and redirect to a
  strongly typed view
- b) Edit web.config customErrors section to point to your strongly
  typed view. However, doing b) can be flakey as other have found e.g.
  [benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages)

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own `HandleError` attribute and register it on `FilterConfig` instead of the default one. Your custom one will extend the default attribute, overriding the result so the model instance passed into the view is of the required type:

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //When already handled, do nothing
        if (context.ExceptionHandled)
            return;

        //Run the base functionality
        base.OnException(context);

        //If the base functionality didnt handle the exception, then exit (as the exception is not of the type this filter should handle)
        if (!context.ExceptionHandled) return;

        //Set a view as the result           
        context.Result = GetViewResult(context);            
    }

    private ViewResult GetViewResult(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //The model of the error view (YourModelType) will inherit from the base view model required in the layout
        YourModelType model = new YourModelType(context.Exception, ...);
        var result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = View,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<YourModelType>(model),
            TempData = context.Controller.TempData
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then register globally this filter instead of the default `HandleErrorAttribute`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new CustomHandleErrorAttribute());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks nice. I've used Application_Error method but I'll check your code in my spare time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the controller name and the action name that reproduce the error by doing so:

```
public class CustomErrorException: HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult {
            ViewName = "CustomError",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo> { 
                Model = new HandleErrorInfo(
                    exception: filterContext.Exception,
                    controllerName: filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
                    actionName: filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
                ) 
            }
        };

        //You can log your errors here.
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

in the "CustomError.cshtml" view you can do this:
@model HandleErrorInfo
Hey this is a custom error!!!
Controller name: @Model.ControllerName
action name: @Model.ActionName
Exception message: @Model.Exception.Message