# MVC Custom Error handling issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I'm currently working on an MVC application.  My issue is that I can't get my customerror handling to work correctly.

So essentially what happens is I throw an exception to test this in a controller.  Then the application should redirect the user to ~/Shared/Errors.cshtml but for some reason it doesn't do this.

Here is the code.

Exception being thrown:

```
throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
```

Webconfig file:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
```

ErrorController Code:

```
  public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Error/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Code used in Error.cshtml:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<div class="list-header clearfix">
    <span>Error</span>
</div>
<div class="list-sfs-holder">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        An unexpected error has occurred. Please contact the system administrator.
    </div>
    @if (Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>Exception:</b> @Model.Exception.Message<br />
                <b>Controller:</b> @Model.ControllerName<br />
                <b>Action:</b> @Model.ActionName
            </p>
            <div style="overflow:scroll">
                <pre>
                    @Model.Exception.StackTrace
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give

Comment: Check it by <customErrors mode="On"/>?Does it work?

Comment: Please check this [article](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc).

Comment: I have answered similar question recently, see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357340/asp-mvc-handleerror-attribute-doesnt-work/26359455#26359455

Comment: @Connor Have you used the HandleError attribute for handling the exceptions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you should return view like this.

```
return View("~/Views/Shared/Errors.cshtml");
```