# Can't find an Error page although an Error view exists ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, custom-error-pages

In an ASP.NET MVC web application I'm working on I am showing na Error view when there is an uncaught error in the application. In the Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" />
```

Controller:

```
 public class ErrorController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And I have a view in folder Views/Error, Index.cshtml. Its content is not important for the issue I'm facing.

When there is for example an error 404 everything works OK - the Error Index.cshtml page is shown(with the URL `http://localhost:51099/Error?aspxerrorpath=/Home/ssad`, which is OK) and in the application's error log the 404 error is reported. But when there is some other error, for example when I try to create a file in non-existing folder through my application, the Error Index.cshtml view is shown(with the URL `http://localhost:51099/Error?aspxerrorpath=/AdminDataExport/ResponseMatrix`, which is OK) but there are two errors reported - one that the folder cannot be found which is OK, and the other is:

```
The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports 
the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/AdminDataExport/Error.aspx
~/Views/AdminDataExport/Error.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
~/Views/AdminDataExport/Error.cshtml
~/Views/AdminDataExport/Error.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml
```

Why does the application search for an Error file in this locations, when I have an ErrorController and a corresponding view defined? Why does this second error appear in some cases and in some don't?

I want to fix the second error. I tried fixing it with adding an Error.cshtml file in the Views/Shared. The result is that the second error is not being logged which is what I want, but the URL is different from the first error - `http://localhost:51099/AdminDataExport/ResponseMatrix` and I want it to be `http://localhost:51099/Error?aspxerrorpath=/AdminDataExport/ResponseMatrix`. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are writing the code now and can work with other approaches, check my answer in this question, it may help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357340/asp-mvc-handleerror-attribute-doesnt-work/26359455#26359455

Comment: @SBirthare I implemented your solution and I have two questions. One is on the line `controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);`. On the "ex" I get a warning "Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute". Second is that when I produce an error it gives me a source code(HTML) of my error page, not the rendered page. Have you had any similar experience? How to solve this situation?

Comment: I did not added extra check for ex in this line, have not tested for that condition. You can add a check. On second question, this method invoke an action on ErrorController based on error code. You can decide what to return from that action. In my case i return corresponding view. Hope this help.

Comment: On you second question, I get to see proper page based on error. It is working in production too so something different in our setup. Can you add more information (in a separate Q may be) around what's happening after the implementation I may be able to help.

Comment: @SB There is not much to tell...Your solution is rendering the page well when the error is not 404. When the error is 404 I get literally a Page Source displayed on the browser...And I put for all errors to go to Error/Index.

Comment: I'm having this same exact problem...it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Ah Ha!

Found the answer...

MVC Adds the FilterConfig class with the following code.

```
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
```

Just remove it and the errors are gone!