# HttpException is not caught by exception filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I had some issues in my test project. 
C#, ASP .NET MVC 5, >NET Framework 4.5.1

For some reason, my exception filter cannot catch HttpException, thrown by controller.
Controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(HttpException), View = "Error")]
    public ViewResult Test()
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "Not found!");
        return View();
    }
```

Error view:

```
@model HandleErrorInfo 
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Sorry, something went wrong!";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BasicLayout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Error: @Model.Exception.Message</h1>
<h1>Status code: @Response.StatusCode</h1>
<div style="display:none;">@Model.Exception.StackTrace</div>
```

I've wrote a customErrors directive in my web.config and set mode attribute to "on" and defaultRedirect attribute to /Content/StaticError.html

StaticError.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
   <h1>ERROR</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried throwing several exceptions like ArgumentOutOfRange, NullReference and some others. And I got a custon Error view as a response.
But hen I am throwing HttpException without changing anything in code above I get redirected to StaticError.html.

How can I throw an HttpException and get a custom error view instead of yellow screed of death or that default redicrect page?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.MVC HandleError attribute doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357340/asp-mvc-handleerror-attribute-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpException` is a special exception type known to `ASP.MVC` pipeline, its purpose is to return HTTP response with specific error code, which doesn't actually mean uncontrolled server error, so default `HandleErrorAttribute` does nothing on `HttpException` with code other than 500. Look [here](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs#L79).

Comment: Ok, I got it. So I guess I have to implement my HandleError. Thanks